# Изменить расстояние между блоками DIV и принудительно установить высоту и ширину картинок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, как изменить расстояние между блоками DIV и принудительно установить высоту и ширину картинок? Принудительно через width не получается

```
/* Общие стили */
*, *:after, *:before { 
    border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { 
    content: ''; 
    display: table; 
}
.clearfix:after { 
    clear: both; 
}
.hover-text-one {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
        height: 50%
}
.hover-text-one figure {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #527c82;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hover-text-one figure img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.hover-text-one figure figcaption {
    padding: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.hover-text-one figure figcaption::before,
.hover-text-one figure figcaption::after {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.hover-text-one figure figcaption{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.hover-text-one figure h3 {
    word-spacing: -0.15em;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.hover-text-one figure h3 span {
    font-weight: 500;
}
.hover-text-one figure h3,
.hover-text-one figure p {
    margin: 0;
}
.hover-text-one figure p {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 60%;
}

/* Эффект при наведении */
figure.effect-text-three {
    background: #000;
}
figure.effect-text-three img {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% + 20px);
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
figure.effect-text-three:hover img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
figure.effect-text-three figcaption {
    text-align: left;
}
figure.effect-text-three h3 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
figure.effect-text-three h3::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}
figure.effect-text-three:hover h3::after {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
figure.effect-text-three p {
    padding: 1em 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
figure.effect-text-three:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```
    <div class="hover-text-one">
 <figure class="effect-text-three"> <img src="/upload/medialibrary/804/yz65nx8r3tml9g7796ukcw7k4vk0p83a.png" alt=""> <figcaption>
        <h4>Диагностика</h4>
        <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </p>
 </figcaption> </figure>
    </div>


    <div class="hover-text-one">
 <figure class="effect-text-three"> <img src="/upload/medialibrary/d7a/mkieup0sgho0fi03hd8y4zjvy693dofx.png" alt=""> <figcaption>
        <h4>Лаборатория</h4>
        <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </p>
 </figcaption> </figure>
    </div>


    <div class="hover-text-one">
 <figure class="effect-text-three"> <img src="/upload/medialibrary/1e7/xej68wggo00cyo2yp075mu1eji2uqro2.png" alt=""> <figcaption>
        <h4>Прием специалистов</h4>
        <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </p>
 </figcaption> </figure>
    </div>


    <div class="hover-text-one">
 <figure class="effect-text-three"> <img src="/upload/medialibrary/c4f/oyi2k1bpb2a985wv3ii3rsek08f56ssa.jpg" alt=""> <figcaption>
        <h4>Медицинские справки</h4>
        <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </p>
 </figcaption> </figure>
    </div>


    <div class="hover-text-one">
 <figure class="effect-text-three"> <img src="/upload/medialibrary/e9d/jhsucl71grij20j3gf79e89e4tpriz0h.png" alt=""> <figcaption>
        <h4>Медицинские услуги на дому</h4>
        <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </p>
 </figcaption> </figure>
    
</div>

    <div class="hover-text-one">
 <figure class="effect-text-three"> <img src="/upload/medialibrary/c4f/oyi2k1bpb2a985wv3ii3rsek08f56ssa.jpg" alt=""> <figcaption>
        <h4>Физиотерапия, Массаж</h4>
        <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </p>
 </figcaption> </figure>
    </div>


    <div class="hover-text-one">
 <figure class="effect-text-three"> <img src="/upload/medialibrary/ac3/1h2gm27e1p20hxumj866f7zd7zninboe.png" alt=""> <figcaption>
        <h4>Дневной стационар</h4>
        <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </p>
 </figcaption> </figure>
    
</div>

    <div class="hover-text-one">
 <figure class="effect-text-three"> <img src="/upload/medialibrary/7da/aw79kc061i3bx3j2w79gopruro4cg8r9.png" alt=""> <figcaption>
        <h6>Предварительные и периодические медицинские осмотры</h6>
        <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </p>
 </figcaption> </figure>
    
</div>

    <div class="hover-text-one">
 <figure class="effect-text-three"> <img src="/upload/medialibrary/0a7/sp9g4zx6bk25jcvzi27eetqj77eh12fz.png" alt=""> <figcaption>
        <h4>Комплексное обследование здоровья (Чек-Ап)</h4>
        <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </p>
 </figcaption> </figure>
    </div>

 <br>
```